# Save claims to db on login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

I have an MVC5 application that is using Oauth and is logging in correctly however I want to save the returned email to the database and am having trouble doing this.

I have the following code in startup.auth.cs:

The below code adds the claim fine and I can the email claim in the debugger, however if it is the users first login then the user isn't actually created at this point so I can't update the user here.

```
LinkedInAuthenticationOptions x = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions();
x.ClientId = "key";
x.ClientSecret = "key";
x.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");

x.Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
    {
        //Get the access token
        context.Identity.AddClaim(
        new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Email", context.Email));
    }
};

app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(x);
```

In the below code (in the default project accountcontroller.cs) I try to access the email claim that I added above however it is unable to find the claim...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
     ClaimsIdentity identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
}
```

Does anybody know how I can access the email claim that I added in startup.auth.cs ?

Comment: How did you solve this. Can you please share your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something similar to this blog post, just store the email claim instead of the Facebook access token.

[How to get more data from external providers?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx)